# How do I make View's asList() sortable in Google Dataflow SDK?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We have a problem making `asList()` method sortable.

We thought we could do this by just extending the View class and override the asList method but realized that View class has a private constructor so we could not do this.

Our other attempt was to fork the Google Dataflow code on github and modify the `PCollectionViews` class to return a sorted list be using the Collections.sort method as shown in the code snippet below

```java
@Override
protected List<T> fromElements(Iterable<WindowedValue<T>> contents) {
    Iterable<T> itr = Iterables.transform(
        contents,
        new Function<WindowedValue<T>, T>() {
          @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
          @Override
          public T apply(WindowedValue<T> input){
            return input.getValue();
          }
        });

    LOG.info("#### About to start sorting the list !");
    List<T> tempList = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (T element : itr) {
      tempList.add(element);
    };
    Collections.sort((List<? extends Comparable>) tempList);
    LOG.info("##### List should now be sorted !");
    return ImmutableList.copyOf(tempList);
}
```

Note that we are now sorting the list.

This seemed to work, when run with the DirectPipelineRunner but when we tried the BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner, it didn't seem like the code change was being executed.

Note: We actually recompiled the dataflow used it in our project but this did not work.

How can we be able to achieve this (as sorted list from the `asList` method call)?

Answer (score 2):

The classes in `PCollectionViews` are not intended for extension. Only the primitive view types provided by `View.asSingleton`, `View.asSingleton` `View.asIterable`, `View.asMap`, and `View.asMultimap` are supported.

To obtain a sorted list from a `PCollectionView`, you'll need to sort it after you have read it. The following code demonstrates the pattern.

```java
// Assume you have some PCollection
PCollection<MyComparable> myPC = ...;

// Prepare it for side input as a list
final PCollectionView<List<MyComparable> myView = myPC.apply(View.asList());

// Side input the list and sort it
someOtherValue.apply(
    ParDo.withSideInputs(myView).of(
        new DoFn<A, B>() {
          @Override
          public void processElement(ProcessContext ctx) {
            List<MyComparable> tempList =
                Lists.newArrayList(ctx.sideInput(myView));
            Collections.sort(tempList);
            // do whatever you want with sorted list 
          }
        }));
```

Of course, you may not want to sort it repeatedly, depending on the cost of sorting vs the cost of materializing it as a new `PCollection`, so you can output this value and read it as a new side input without difficulty:

```java
// Side input the list, sort it, and put it in a PCollection
PCollection<List<MyComparable>> sortedSingleton = Create.<Void>of(null).apply(
    ParDo.withSideInputs(myView).of(
        new DoFn<Void, B>() {
          @Override
          public void processElement(ProcessContext ctx) {
            List<MyComparable> tempList =
                Lists.newArrayList(ctx.sideInput(myView));
            Collections.sort(tempList);
            ctx.output(tempList);
          }
        }));

// Prepare it for side input as a list
final PCollectionView<List<MyComparable>> sortedView =
    sortedSingleton.apply(View.asSingleton());

someOtherValue.apply(
    ParDo.withSideInputs(sortedView).of(
        new DoFn<A, B>() {
          @Override
          public void processElement(ProcessContext ctx) {
            ... ctx.sideInput(sortedView) ...
            // do whatever you want with sorted list 
          }
        }));
```

You may also be interested in the unsupported [sorter](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/tree/master/contrib/sorter) contrib module for doing larger sorts using both memory and local disk.

Answer (score 0):

We tried to do it the way Ken Knowles suggested. There's a problem for large datasets. If the tempList is large (so sort takes some measurable time as it's proportion to O(n * log n)) and if there are millions of elements in the "someOtherValue" PCollection, then we are unecessarily re-sorting the same list millions of times. We should be able to sort ONCE and FIRST, before passing the list to the someOtherValue.apply's DoFn.

Comment: Hello! I missed your parallel answer. I've updated my answer to address your concerns. If you have any further questions, you can add them as a comment on my answer to be sure I receive a notification.